# Survey 2018 missing several US Territories

Tags: bug, survey-2018

In the 2018 Survey, if you select the USA as your country of residence, you are asked:

> In which state or territory of the USA do you live? *This information will be kept private.*

The list presented to the user has the District of Columbia as well as the territory of Puerto Rico, but is missing the other so-called ["Insular Areas"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insular_area):

- US Virgin Islands
- Guam
- American Samoa
- Northern Mariana Islands

Can they be added? I am not personally affected by this as I do not live in one of the missing territories, but it's highly likely that someone here *does*.

Comment: Is there a lot of software jobs on Samoa or the Northern Mariana Islands?

Comment: I mean, Saipan, Rota, Samoa etc, are not the kind of places I associate with software development work.  They are the kind of place where I would go to avoid software development work :)

Comment: Islands can be nice places to work from remotely! Plus I imagine there's loads of US military personnel on Guam, that *has* to include the odd programmer

Comment: I wanna go!   I don't like it here.  It's cold and damp.  I prefer chicken and coconut to tikka masala.  I want a beach bar with a laptop and satellite dish.  Please, SO, put these places in on the remote chance I can get a contract there.

Comment: The U.S. Pacific islands are likely to have at least a few software developers, since there are DoD installations there.  There are quite a few developers, for example, on Kwajalein Atoll in the Marshall Islands, which although legally independent from the U.S. since 1979, continues to host what is now the Ronald Reagan Ballistic Missile Defense Test Site.   I imagine there are similar activities in the Pacific territories.

Comment: Maybe let's try to answer the question the other way around: How does it hurt to have those options in the survey?

Comment: @MartinJames Well, there's no way for us to know, since any developers living there have no way to indicate that on the developer survey. And that's kind of the point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been acknowledged by the SO folks in "[What needs to be done to get US Territories added to Developer Survey?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379529/what-needs-to-be-done-to-get-us-territories-added-to-developer-survey)" and US Territories should be included in the 2020 Developer Survey.