# 2019 Developer Survey doesn't provide for Guam developers

Tags: support, survey-2019

The 2019 Developer Survey doesn't have an option for Guam developers. Guam is sometimes listed as a country, but isn't an option in the country list here. When I select United States of America, the next step in the survey asks to select a state or territory, and Guam is not listed there either.

Can this be changed or am I missing another option?

Comment: Related: [Survey 2018 missing several US Territories](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361820/6471538)

Comment: Looks like this was just marked as an exact duplicate of an unresolved ticket about last year's survey. I'm a neat freak too, I understand the need to organize, but doesn't that just squash the chance of anything being done to resolve this ticket?

Question: what can I do to get Guam and other US territories added to the survey?

Comment: Why not to upvote already created question instead of opening the same new one?

Comment: @leftjoin I didn't know of an existing question when I asked it. Actually, I still don't think there was a question that addressed the 2019 survey and feel this one was incorrectly marked as a duplicate. Further, to make the point of why you can/should open another question, I created [a better phrased question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379529/what-needs-to-be-done-to-get-us-territories-added-to-developer-survey) and got the problem addressed.