# What needs to be done to get US Territories added to Developer Survey?

Tags: feature-request, bug, survey-2019

In "[2019 Developer Survey doesn't provide for Guam developers](/q/379449)" I pointed out that the 2019 Developer Survey doesn't include Guam. It was closed as a duplicate of "[Survey 2018 missing several US Territories](/q/361820)". Here I'd like to ask the community what can be done to get Guam, and the other US Territories, added to the survey.

In the response to "[2018 Developer Survey - Missing Country/Territory](/q/361661)" I see that an initial stock list was used but it can be amended by the wonderful folks behind Stack Overflow. I'm new to the 'meta' side so am not sure where to start.

Without getting into the politics of it, the minimum list of missing territories to add would be:

- Puerto Rico
- Guam
- Northern Mariana Islands
- U.S. Virgin Islands
- American Samoa

Comment: If you're wanting "to ask the community what can be done to get Guam, and the other US Territories, added to the survey," you probably want a discussion question; likewise, if you're looking to directly ask the people in charge of the survey questions to add the territories in the future, then feature-request is the right tag.

Comment: Good to know, thanks @Davy M

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was an oversight on our part, and we apologize. Due to the number of responses we have already received, it's too late to make the correction to the 2019 survey. We will definitely put this on our list of things to fix for the 2020 survey.

Comment: Thanks Anita, shame it won't make it into this year's survey, looking forward to representing Guam in 2020! =)

Comment: Would it be worthwhile having a public beta? There's only so much that can be done by the internal beta testers.

Comment: We did have an external beta with 1,600 developers, but this issue wasn't one of the ones that got flagged. @Pureferret

Comment: Good to know Anita